# how can i add title to angular datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

```js
$scope.dtColumns = [ 
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('employee.employeeCode').withTitle("Employeecode").withOption('autoWidth', false), 
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('employee.workMailId') .withTitle("Official Email"), 
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('employee.joiningDate') .withTitle("Joining Date").renderWith(function(data, type) { 
        return $filter('date')(data, baseConstant.displayDateInTable); //date filter 
    });
```

This controller is for employee report ........so i want to first set title EMPLOYEE REPORT before showing columns and its records

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings for a title or header in dataTables. But you can create one by yourself. To achieve that you can use dataTables [**`dom`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option, which makes it easy to inject extra elements into the dataTables wrapper. You can inject a `<div id="dt-title">` just before the table, but after the length menu and the search box by (`lfrtip` is default) by :

```js
.withDOM('lf<"#dt-title">rtip')
```

when initialisation has completed set content of `dt-title` :

```js
.withOption('initComplete', function() {
   document.querySelector('#dt-title').textContent = 'EMPLOYEE REPORT'
})
```

style `dt-title` as any other element, just remember `clear: both` :

```css
#dt-title {
   clear: both;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
   padding: 15px 5px 10px 10px;
}
```

see it working here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/Xl6h5pdcPp8d2MvOn9lx?p=preview**